# Replace div in HTML with fetch() data using JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch

I'm using `fetch()` to obtain data from a public API and have an array where I'm trying to store all job locations. This array is called the `locations_array`.

A `for loop` is running to generate a `.card` for each `key` found in the JSON and in this loop, I'm running `locations_array.push(job_location);` to add the locations to the array.

In my HTML I have a `div` in my `select` where I'm looking for the markup from JS to replace:

```
<select>
   <option value="">OPEN POSITIONS</option>
   <div id="location__options"></div>
</select>
```

So, `location__options` will be replaced with the `option` markup I have written in my for loop JS.

**Full code here:**

```js
fetch('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/cutover/jobs?content=true', {})

  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json(); // response type (json)
  })

  .then(function (data) {
    appendDataToHTML(data); // function that appends data to HTML
  })

  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


  function appendDataToHTML(data) {
    const filterContainer = document.getElementById("location__options");
    const mainContainer = document.getElementById("jobListing");

    // for each object, create card
    var locations_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <  Object.keys(data.jobs).length; i++) {
      const job_title = data.jobs[i].title;
      const job_location = data.jobs[i].location.name;
      locations_array.push(job_location);

      console.log(locations_array[i]);


      const html =
        '<div class="card">'+
          '<div class="card__body--title">'+
            '<span class="jobTitle">' + job_title + '</span><br>' +
            '<span class="jobLocation">' + job_location + '</span>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>';

      // const filter_html = '<option>' + locations_array [i]+ '</option>';

      // document.getElementById("location__options").innerHTML = "<option>" + locations_array [i]+ "</option>";

      mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    }
  }
```

```css
select, .card{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="workable__filters">
        <div class="workable__select">
        
          <select>
            <option value="">OPEN POSITIONS</option>
            <div id="location__options"></div>
          </select>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="jobListing"></div>
    </div>
```

**What I've tried:**

1.

```
document.getElementById("location__options").innerHTML = "<option>" + locations_array [i]+ "</option>";
```

With the above I get the console error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

2.

```
const filterContainer = document.getElementById("location__options");
const filter_html = '<option>' + locations_array [i]+ '</option>';
filterContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', filter_html);
```

With the above, I get the console error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null`

I just want the locations to be shown as `options` in the `select`

Comment: I believe a `div` tag inside a `select` is not a valid syntax, maybe that't why getting it by id returns `null`

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close, you just need something like this:

Change your select tag to look like this:

```html
<select id="location__options">
    <option value="">OPEN POSITIONS</option>
</select>
```

this means we can target the select tag itself, we don't need a div.

Then you can create an optionTag every iteration of the loop and append it to the select tag:

```js
const optionTag = document.createElement('option');
optionTag.value = job_title;
optionTag.innerHTML = job_title + " | " + job_location;

filterContainer.appendChild(optionTag);
```

Full example:

```js
fetch('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/cutover/jobs?content=true', {})

  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json(); // response type (json)
  })

  .then(function (data) {
    appendDataToHTML(data); // function that appends data to HTML
  })

  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


  function appendDataToHTML(data) {
    const filterContainer = document.getElementById("location__options");
    const mainContainer = document.getElementById("jobListing");

    // for each object, create card
    var locations_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <  Object.keys(data.jobs).length; i++) {
      const job_title = data.jobs[i].title;
      const job_location = data.jobs[i].location.name;
      locations_array.push(job_location);

      console.log(locations_array[i]);


      const html =
        '<div class="card">'+
          '<div class="card__body--title">'+
            '<span class="jobTitle">' + job_title + '</span><br>' +
            '<span class="jobLocation">' + job_location + '</span>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>';

      // const filter_html = '<option>' + locations_array [i]+ '</option>';

      // document.getElementById("location__options").innerHTML = "<option>" + locations_array [i]+ "</option>";
      
      const optionTag = document.createElement('option');
      optionTag.value = job_title;
      optionTag.innerHTML = job_title + " | " + job_location;
      
      filterContainer.appendChild(optionTag);

      mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    }
  }
```

```css
select, .card{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="workable__filters">
        <div class="workable__select">
        
          <select id="location__options">
            <option value="">OPEN POSITIONS</option>
          </select>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id="jobListing"></div>
    </div>
```